# Need to omit the data that matches in two tables in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to solve the below problem , please suggest

I have two tables wanted to remove the only matched records that are present in the Table 2.
NOTE: Even if there are common keys available in tables if table 2 has 1 record  then it should only
remove 1 record of the table 1 comprising of the same key,
INPUT:

```
Table 1:
1,Sam,5000
1,Sam,5000
1,Sam,5000
2,Boo,3000

Table 2:
1,Sam,5000
2,Boo,3000

OUTPUT:
1,Sam,5000
1,Sam,5000
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the Set Difference between the two relations.
Source: [See here](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/guide/set-operations.html) .You will have to download the jar file that supports the functions from [here](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/quick-start.html) .The jar is distributed under [Apache License](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)

```
register datafu-pig-incubating-1.3.0.jar
define SetDifference datafu.pig.sets.SetDifference();

A = LOAD 'test1.txt' as (a1:int,a2:chararray,a3:chararray);
B = LOAD 'test2.txt' as (b1:int,b2:chararray,b3:chararray);

diff = FOREACH A {
                   a1 = ORDER A by a1;
                   b1 = ORDER B by b1;
                   GENERATE SetDifference(a1,b1);
                 }

DUMP diff;
```